# Handle back press on a activity where only UI data update on click?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity

I am working on an android app where I update only UI on click in an activity.

I am showing a list of item.. on Click I check it `has_child` list or not.... if `true` I load that child list again on the same activity.

I want to go back in the sequence that I loaded child lists on the back press.

kindly help if some have a solution for it.

Comment: It isn't clear what your problem is. Please formulate your question better or give an example of what isn't working or show the problem code.

Comment: I think I explained enough. what is not understandable to you? I just want to pop out in the same sequence in which am going.

Comment: The default behaviour of Android is to return to the previous `Activity` when you press the BACK key. You don't need to do anything special to get this standard default behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we are not loading new activity what would happen is that back button will try to pop your list view. 
To achieve desired behavior please try intercepting back press on key. Lets assume you write onBackPress(); 
Also you will need to maintain stack on which lists were opened and in what sequence and then you can pop it out.

Comment: you got the question correct. Thanks.  just overriding onBackPress(); worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the behaviour of the Back Press Button of your Activity like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//Do your code here
}
```

Comment: `@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
super.onBackPressed();
}`  worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, this makes no sense at all! Overriding `onBackPressed()` and calling `super.onBackPressed()` is exactly the same as not overriding `onBackPressed()` at all! There is absolutely no difference.